# how to correctly start a redhat linux service?

Tags: bash, service, redhat

I have definied a service and put in folder /etc/rc.d/init.d/somename, it's put in chkconfig with level 2-5 on.

However, when I run `service somename start,` it is not started. However if i run `somename start` directly, it is started,

Which part did I got it wrong?

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Startup script for xxx
#
# chkconfig: 2345 99 99
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

prog="file"


start() {
    echo -n $"Starting : "
    echo
    daemon  /path/to/some/file
    let RETVAL=RETVAL+$?
    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    if test "x`pidof -x $prog`" != x; then
        echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
        killproc  $prog
        echo
    fi
    RETVAL=$?
    return $RETVAL
}

case "$1" in
        start)
            start
            ;;

        stop)
            stop
            ;;

        status)
            echo $prog
            status $prog
            ;;

        restart)
            stop
            start
            ;;
        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
            exit 1

esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to be correct.

You can add `set -x` to the start of the script, start it once again and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the script was indeed right. The problem was caused by the service itself that exited during the process.